# How can I run images on my Java Applet without having to sign it?

Tags: java, applet

I'm new to Java programming and it seems to me like they are making this Applet signing more difficult than it needs to be...no website is straightforward on how to do it, and it gives the feeling that it would be time-consuming.

The problem is that I keep getting the "access denied" message when I try to run images on my Applet using the `drawImage` function.

I was told `Class.getResourceAsStream` would help, but I am having a hard time trying to find information on how I would implement this precisely for an image. There is also the issue that I am using NetBeans, [some of this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/LoadimagefromfileaninputstreamandClassgetResourceAsStream.htm) information that I find is out of my league of understanding or just doesn't fit what I need it for.

This is the kind of program I am trying to run:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class JavaProject extends JApplet
{
    Image img;

    public void init()
    {
        img=getImage(getDocumentBase(),"/Image.jpg");
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);

        g.drawImage(img,20,20,this);
    }
}
```

And this is the HTML file I am running it from:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> My First Web Page </title>
</head>

<body>
    <applet code="JavaProject.class" width="500" height="600">
    </applet>
</body>
</html>
```

It works with shapes just fine, but I want to implement images like this and this is where I encounter the issue. Basically, I just want to see how `Class.getResourceAsStream` would fit into that code there, because that code above gives me the "access denied" error.

Also, something to note is that I am running this from the file system, not from HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java 7 you need to sign applets now:

> Most significant is a new requirement that all Java applets and Web
>   Start Applications using the Java plug-in to run in browsers be signed
>   with a trusted certificate for the best user experience.   Java
>   supports code signing, but until Java SE 7u21 it was an optional
>   feature. Application code signing provides numerous security benefits
>   to users.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/java-code-signing-1915323.html

However, you can change the security settings through the Java Control Panel. (On Windows just Start > Java > Configure Java.)  In the Java Control Panel, go to the security tab and set the Security Level to the minimal (medium).  I believe this allows you to run an applet after only a security prompt.